# Text-decoration with border-bottom, ul vertical center - li's "jumps" when hovering on it

Tags: html, css

I'm just interested in solution with CSS.

I have some nav contain ul, with some li items inside. So my question how to underline this li with border-bottom? One more condition is that nav have static height, and I want, that ul will be in the centre (horizontally and vertically).

Here's what I have now. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AleshaOleg/35rwv892/)

HTML:

```
<nav>    
    <ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">6</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

and CSS:

```
nav {
    height: 120px;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: table;
}

#menu {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    list-style-type: none;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 0;
}

#menu > li {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    float: left;
    width: inherit;
    padding: 0 25px 0 25px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#menu > li > a {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#menu > li:hover {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #000;
}

#menu li a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

I tried a lot, but still no result. Here are what I tried:

1. :after - make some div after li, but I can't get the width of each
   li;
2. adding margin-top when hover, to all other li with :not (like #main > li:hover(:not) - that's construction work, but not for this situation);
3. adding margin-top when hover, to ul#main (ul#main take the whole height of nav);

The main problem is: li jumps when I hover on it.

Maybe you know another method of vertical-align of ul or add margin-top to ul, but I tried every which I know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To prevent the "jumping", compensate for your 3px border by adding a 3px bottom pad when the border is not in use (not hover), and remove padding when the border is in use (hover).

```
#menu > li {
    ...
    padding: 0 25px 3px 25px;
    ...}


#menu > li:hover {
    ...
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    ....}
```

**Updated Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/seadonk/kppzqqo3/